# Post route map on facebook newsfeed

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I would like to post travel offer (route on map) from my website to Facebook newsfeed and timeline. Offer posting works well, but there is one issue. It looks different on my timeline, and on Facebook newsfeed.

Timeline:
http://i44.tinypic.com/34heu6t.jpg

Newsfeed:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=20if0qb&s=5#.Uo3jacR0m30

I would like display route on map in newsfeed as well. I was trying with attachments, inherit from map objects, and collections, still the same.

It would be great help If someone knows why it's happen.